# When using env.yml with conda whats the difference between dependencies and pip dependencies?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am creating a .SH script for setting up automatically my dev environment in Azure ML, according to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/machine-learning/how-to-customize-compute-instance

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
set -e
# https://pypi.org/project/azure-ai-ml/ 
# Requires: Python <4.0, >=3.7
# This script creates a custom conda environment and kernel based on a sample yml file.

conda env create  python=3.10
#conda env create -f env.yml

echo "Activating new conda environment"
conda activate envname
conda install -y ipykernel
echo "Installing kernel"
sudo -u azureuser -i <<'EOF'
conda activate envname
python -m ipykernel install --user --name envname --display-name "mykernelp310v2"
echo "Conda environment setup successfully."
pip install azure-ai-ml
EOF
```

my env looks like this:

```
name: p310v2

dependencies:
  - python=3.10
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - pip:
       -kaggle==1.5
```

When I check this document:

https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/introduction-to-conda-for-data-scientists/04-sharing-environments/index.html

I am confused between the dependencies section and the pip section.  For example scikit-learn I could put in dependencies but also on the pip section, so whats the deal here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dependencies` are `conda` dependencies; listing them is equivalent to run `conda install <deps>`. For example `conda` installs `numpy` from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy .

`pip` means pip dependencies for `pip install` command; `pip` installs them from PyPI.org. For example, https://pypi.org/project/numpy/

The same for `scikit-learn`: https://anaconda.org/search?q=scikit-learn and https://pypi.org/search/?q=scikit-learn

See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+%5Bpip%5D+difference

Comment: so I could install  any pip package in the conda dependencies or viceversa, the end result will be the same?

Comment: @LuisValencia No, there're packages available only on Anaconda/conda or only on PyPI/pip. Some package are available on both channels, in that case using `conda` is preferable if you already use `conda`. Use `pip` for projects where you don't use `conda` at all or where packages at Anaconda are not available.